# Laravel And Twitter API as well as thujohn/twitter

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I followed his [readme](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter) and I have done `composer dump-autoload` a million times, but still I receive an error.

The code:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [

    ...
    'Twitter'   => Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter::class,
],
```

In my controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $tweets = Twitter::getUserTimeline([
            'screen_name' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'count'       => 10,
            'format'      => 'json'
        ]);

        dd($tweets);

        return view('home');
    }

    public function about() {
        return view('about');
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 10:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Twitter' not found
```

Um ..... **What?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used non-namespaced name when you refered to **Twitter** class, so PHP is looking for the class in current namespace. Change that reference to **\Twitter** or add the following **use** statement:

```
use Twitter;
```

Comment: I didnt know when you aliased in laravel you still needed the `use` statement

Comment: You do. By creating an alias "Twitter" you're telling PHP which class to use when you reference Twitter class in global namespace. You referenced Twitter in "App\Http\Controllers" namespace so PHP looked for "App\Http\Controllers\Twitter" class for which there is no alias, that's why you needed the use statement

Comment: If that's all, please mark the question as answered

Comment: Stack makes me wait up to 20 minutes sometimes to accept an answer. So please relax